# Is it possible to know last update of data behind a WFS service?

Tags: wfs, metadata

I need to use several WFS service which are not mine and convert them to shapefiles.
I'd like to update the shapefiles whenever the data is updated in the WFS services without downloading the whole data.
Is there a way to know the moment when data changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no universal and reliable way to check when the data in WFS are changed. If the feature type has an attribute for holding a timestamp of the latest update it is of course possible to use that in a filter and read only new features. However, it is impossible to know which features have been deleted without reading the whole feature type and making a comparison. Best you could do is to run a query every day "features which have a timestamp greater than yesterday &maxfeatures=1". If you get a feature back then you know that something has changed and you can refresh the whole feature type at your end. But that works only if data has timestamp as an attribute. Notice that the GML document returned from WFS has a timeStamp attribute which tells only when the document was created. That is not useful for you.

What could be nice for you but not for the WFS service provider is to read the whole feature type on the disk and calculate a check sum. If it is the same than last time there is no need to update the shapefiles. Remember to remove the timeStamp of the document from check sum calculation!

What might work well both for you and service provider is to use WFS 1.1.0 or WFS 2.0.0 and &resulltype=hits for counting the number of features on the layer.

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&resulttype=hits`

If the count is different from what it was last time then for sure something has changed. Unfortunately opposite logic does not hold water. Data may have changed even if the count of hits is the same if only attributes are updated or number of inserts and deletes has remained the same. The hit count is not reliable always if there is a maxFeature limit set on the server side. It can be that server returns in this case always the maxFeatures count as hits for the unfiltered GetFeature request. WFS 2.0.0 has an improved count handling and can suit better for your use case.

Best alternative could be to contact the WFS service provider and ask if they could sent a RSS feed when the data has changed or it can be an Atom feed as well especially if you live in Europe. Atom feeds are accepted alternative for arranging INSPIRE download services.